# How to print onto screen entire file?

Tags: windows, linux, batch-file

How to print onto screen (echo) entire file (all file contents) from given system path on Windows and on Linux?

Comment: Anyone else accidentally read "entire life"?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cat` in Unix and `type` in windows.